# Как упаковать отправляемые запросы в zip через jmeter?

Tags: java, jmeter

Есть ли в jmeter такой плагин или функция, чтобы параметризованные мной запросы упаковывались в zip архив и отправлялись в компонент (адаптер СМЭВ) для тестов производительности?
Или возможно прописать логику в семплере?
Удалось найти только способ скачивания файлов, но это совсем не то.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Если вы хотите записатьтело каждого запроса в .zip файл это можно сделать через [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor)

   Примерный код:

   ```
   def destination = new java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File('putinhuilo.zip')))
   destination.putNextEntry(new java.util.zip.ZipEntry(prev.getSampleLabel() + '.txt'))
   destination << prev.getSamplerData().bytes
   destination.close()
   ```
2. Также можно записать "тело" запроса в отдельный файл при помощи, например, [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#writer) а потом запаковать его или кодом из пункта 1 где-нибудь в [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) или средствами операционной системы через [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler)